# Words with several grammatical meanings in stanford nlp?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a case where in my language one word has three meaning that are specified in the dictionary. For example the word "како" in macedonian language can be preposition,adverb and a conjunction. My question is how to solve the problem with showing the correct word meaning when searching for some sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

The Stanford POS Tagger calculates tags based on a bidirectional approach. The POS tag of a word is calculated based on the context it appears in, meaning that two words before and two words after are considered. Based on that the algorithm outputs the tag which is most likely to be correct. 
In different constellations of sentences one and the same word can have different POS tags, but one word has only one tag at a time. There is no option to get all tags which exceed a certain probability.

As far as I know there is no model for the macedonian langauge yet. You could of course Train your own model, which might then be able to handle your use case correctly. For more Information on training your own model see [here](http://renien.com/blog/training-stanford-pos-tagger/) or [here](https://medium.com/@klintcho/training-a-swedish-pos-tagger-for-stanford-corenlp-546e954a8ee7).

Comment: Okey... How can I for some word to extract from the dictionary all the possible variations that exist for that word from the database using POS Tagger, because as a result it always returns only the first word from the existing three for example.

Comment: Like stated above, you can't. The only option to get multiple POS tags for the same word is to give the tagger multiple sentences containing the same word in different contexts. There is no simple way to get all possible POS tags for a word, because the POS tag is calculated based on the context the word appears in.